# Setting background image to paper using Raphael-JS

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am using Raphael-js to for creating a chart;  Is it possible to set a background image for the Rapahel paper?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest you to add an image with :

```
var img = paper.image("foo.png", 10, 10, 80, 80);
img.attr({ "clip-rect": "20,20,30,30" });
```

The image is drawn with clipping to clip out the part you want, and you can control the offset of the image either with `img.translate(x,y)` or by the `paper.image`.

Comment: Thank You. I should have figured it out by myself ;(